# Does the kernel support a BMP180 BMP85 digital pressure sensor out of the box?

Tags: sensor, kernel, driver, bmp180

The kernel generates a virtual file with the values for the famous temperature sensor `DS 18B20`.

Is there a `plug and play` kernel support for the I2C digital pressure sensors 
`BMP180` and `BMP85` too?

And if so, what is the minimal kernel version?

Answer (score 1):

The kernel has drivers for the bmp085 and bmp18x digital barometric pressure and temperature sensors from Bosch Sensortec.

```
drivers/misc/bmp085.c
drivers/misc/bmp085-spi.c
drivers/misc/bmp085.h
drivers/misc/bmp085-i2c.c
Documentation/devicetree/bindings/misc/bmp085.txt
```

I don't think they are compiled into the kernel by default so you'll have to build your own kernel.

Why not just use I2C?

Comment: Can I use the listed drivers optionally to a standard I2C driver?

Comment: I don't know what happens if you enable the kernel drivers and then attempt to use ordinary I2C to access the device.  I suspect they would co-exist happily enough but that is a pure guess.  I don't know of anyone using the BMP085 kernel drivers on the Pi.  There are plenty of posts from people who use the ordinary I2C drivers to read the chip.